# How does the python interpreter send information to the Pycharm on hitting breakpoints?

Tags: python, debugging

When using breakpoints in Pycharm and other IDEs, how does the line-number, and variable state get to the IDE ?

I want to implement my own program that can watch variables / set breakpoints and receive info when they are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a built in debugger that handles the brains of code inspection. Pycharm just uses that with added features and a GUI.

docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html